# Windows 10 host - Very Slow Ubuntu 18.04 64bit on VMWare

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, vmware

I have two new machines running VMWare player, Ubuntu 18.04 runs too slowly to use on both.

AMD Ryzen 5 1600 CPU, Gigabyte AB-350 motherboard, 16 GB ram, Samsung 970 EVO hard drive, NVidia 1060 graphics

The other machine is a Dell latitude 7480, not nearly as beefy, but both machines run Ubuntu extremely slowly/unusable.

I have routinely run Ubuntu under VMWare player to surf the internet.  It does not work on this version of Ubuntu/VMWare Player on either machine.

Any advice?

Thanks,
Whit

Comment: Host runs fine, it's only Ubuntu that is slow

Comment: In recent versions of VMware up to 2GB of video memory can be allocated for additional workload processing power. On the AMD Ryzen 5 1600 computer give the Ubuntu guest OS all 2GB of video memory, 2 virtual CPU cores and 8GB virtual base memory. Provide the specs of the Dell Latitude 7480 and I'll post a recommendation. Something like half the physical RAM and 2 CPU cores, maybe 1GB of video memory.

Comment: Working on it now, thanks for the input Karel.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of VMware up to 2GB of video memory can be allocated for additional workload processing power. VMware Workstation 15 and later supports virtual graphics memory up to 3GB. On the AMD Ryzen 5 1600 computer give the Ubuntu guest OS all 2GB of video memory, 2 virtual CPU cores and 8GB virtual base memory. The Dell Latitude's recommended VMware settings are something like half the physical RAM, 2 CPU cores and maybe 1GB of video memory.